# Datagridview - botão remover

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom dia.
Preciso de ajuda para resolver o seguinte problema:
Preciso fazer um projeto na qual eu mesmo insiro um código e nome de uma pessoa para ficar armazenado em um datagridview (windows forms c#), porém quando utilizo a seguinte linha que me foi passada para auxílio, acaba dando erro quando clico no mesmo botão para remover mesmo que não tenha nenhuma row ou célula selecionada, gostaria de ajuda para criar um **if** para que impeça ou que mande uma mensagem para a pessoa que apertar o botão quando nenhuma célula for selecionada.

```
    private void BtnLimparDados_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCodigo.Text = "";
        txtNome.Text = "";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvDados.Rows.Add(txtCodigo.Text, txtNome.Text);
        txtCodigo.Text = "";
        txtNome.Text = "";
        txtNome.Focus();
    }

    private void btnRemover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = dgvDados.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        if (dgvDados.CurrentCell.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("a", "a", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        else

            dgvDados.Rows.RemoveAt(row);

    }

    private void dgvDados_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = e.RowIndex;
        dgvDados.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

O dataGridView foi implementado de um jeito que ele contabiliza a última linha (vazia), por isso você deve conferir antes se não está tentando excluí-la, pois é isso que está causando erro, o código abaixo funcionou perfeitamente aqui, e além disso ele permite excluir seleção múltipla e seleção de linha. Segue:

```
private void btnRemover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var totalDeLinhas = dgvDados.RowCount;
    //Use um hashset para não incluir linhas duplicadas (pode usar linq também)
    HashSet<DataGridViewRow> linhasAfetadas = new HashSet<DataGridViewRow>();

    foreach (DataGridViewCell celula in dgvDados.SelectedCells)
        //Conferir se a linha selecionada não é a última
        if (!celula.OwningRow.IsNewRow)
            linhasAfetadas.Add(celula.OwningRow);

    //Se não houver nenhuma linha afetada mostrar a mensagem de erro
    if (linhasAfetadas.Count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("a", "a", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

    foreach (var linha in linhasAfetadas)
    {
        dgvDados.Rows.Remove(linha);
    }
}
```

Se você não precisar mostrar mensagem de erro fica mais fácil:

```
private void btnRemover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var celulasSelecionadas = dgvDados.SelectedCells;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell celula in celulasSelecionadas)
    {
        if (celula.RowIndex != -1)
            if (!celula.OwningRow.IsNewRow)
                dgvDados.Rows.Remove(celula.OwningRow);
    }
}
```

Ou se preferir usar linq:

```
private void btnRemover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvDados.SelectedCells
        .OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
        .GroupBy(celula => celula.OwningRow)
        .Select(linha => linha.Key)
        .Where(linha => !linha.IsNewRow)
        .ToList<DataGridViewRow>()
        .ForEach(linha => dgvDados.Rows.Remove(linha));
}
```